# swig python template functions with type deduction

Tags: python, c++, swig

I want to wrap following C++ code into python module.

```
class minimal
{
public:
    minimal()
    {
    }
    ~minimal()
    {
    }

    template<class T>
    void foo(T a)
    {
        auto z = a; 
    }
};
```

As you can see, I have template function, and I know that I can't call templated function in Python, however I hope that calling foo with int or string arguments will be succesfull because of type deduction. Still there is no foo in the .cxx file, but SWIG documentation says, that it supports type deduction

So my goal is to python codeworking like this:

```
#C++ analog: minimal.foo(123)
minimal().foo(123) 

#C++: to minimal().foo(0.1)
minimal().foo(0.1)
```

Is it possible? Or my idea is completly wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `%template` directive to instruct SWIG to create implementations of particular templates.  Only the template instances declared will be available.

Example:

```
%module test

%inline %{

class minimal
{
public:
    minimal()
    {
    }
    ~minimal()
    {
    }

    template<class T>
    void foo(T a)
    {
        auto z = a; 
    }
};

%}

%template(foo) minimal::foo<int>;
%template(foo) minimal::foo<double>;
```

Example:

```
>>> import test
>>> m=test.minimal()
>>> m.foo(1)
>>> m.foo(1.5)
>>> m.foo('abc')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\test.py", line 115, in foo
    return _test.minimal_foo(self, *args)
NotImplementedError: Wrong number or type of arguments for overloaded function 'minimal_foo'.
  Possible C/C++ prototypes are:
    minimal::foo< int >(int)
    minimal::foo< double >(double)
```

Comment: thx for an answer, but it looks like automatic type deduction will not work withour explicit telling SWIG how to wrap function. It reminds me explicit instantiation in C++

Comment: @Demaunt In C++, the compiler sees all the uses of a template and generates code for them.  In Python, the extension has already been compiled so `%template` instructs SWIG to generate code for the types you want to support in advance.